# Why does Pandas/Numpy automatically round up 9999999999 to 1.000000e+10?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.6

I have a Pandas dataframe, with 4 rows, and one of the columns (named `limit`) contains floating point values, where any zeros must be replaced with 9999999999 (9.999999999 billion). The column is set to the `float32` data type, and I use the `pandas.DataFrame.where` method to do the replacement. But it's not working as expected because Numpy is rounding up 9999999999 to 10000000000 (10 billion).

I've tried this in iPython 3 (Python 3.6.8), Pandas version 0.24.2, Numpy version 1.14.0.

This is the replacement statement

```
df['limit'] = df['limit'].where(df['limit'] != 0, 9999999999)
```

I'm seeing the following column values for `limit`:

```
0    1.000000e+10
1    1.000000e+10
2    1.000000e+10
3    1.000000e+10
```

but I'm expecting

```
0    9999999999.0
1    9999999999.0
2    9999999999.0
3    9999999999.0
```

Why does the rounding up happen? This doesn't happen with plain Python

```
In [1]: (9.999999999) * 10**9                                                                                                    
Out[1]: 9999999999.0
```

Comment: It smells like a floating point issue, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014), but someone with proper Pandas/NumPy knowledge should confirm.

Comment: A 32-bit floating point number is not precise enough to represent that number exactly. It is not an issue with Pandas, NumPy or Python, it's a limitation in [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) ([see example in C](https://rextester.com/LFPS36800)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because `int32` is not capable of preserving that number. You can check this by calculating the number of bits needed for demonstrating that number:

```
In [24]: np.floor(np.log2(9999999999)) + 1
Out[24]: 34.0
```

As you can see you need at least 34 bits for demonstrating that number. Therefore you should use `int64` as a larger data type for representing it.

Even if you test this by putting the number in a series with same data type you'll see the unexpected result (overflow) again:

```
In [25]: s = pd.Series([9999999999], dtype=pd.np.int32)

In [26]: s
Out[26]: 
0    1410065407
dtype: int32
```

Comment: I think they actually wanted to use float32, which cannot hold that number precisely, hence the "rounding".